# PHP/Apache server setup on Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows

Sorry if this is the wrong place for this question but I'm having a tough time trying to setup server with PHP and Apache on my Windows 10 computer. The best tutorial I've found, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuMTZowwjus), seems to work until I actually try to view the localhost "site" (not even sure if that's the right word) where "There's Nothing Here".

I'm concerned that it might be because I didn't use the exact same version of PHP and/or apache from the video causing some sort of compatibility error (I used the closest version of each to what was used in the video).

Is there something obvious I've missed here?

Please word your reply in relatively simple terms; not only am a newbie at coding, I imagine others trying to do this same thing in the future are going to be just as inexperienced.

Answer (score 0):

If attempting to go to "localhost" doesn't bring up the "Index Of /" page like in the tutorial it is because the "DirectoryIndex" option in httpd.conf is set to index.php, meaning it will automatically redirect to that page if you go to localhost. It's like the default page that will be accessed. If you want to access the info.php file, you must type "localhost/info.php" in directly. think of the "Apache24/httpd" folder as the "Root" folder of your local server, and everthing in the "Root" directory is accessed with "localhost/NAME_OF_FILE"

It may also be possible that Apache is not starting up again automatically after your computer restarted. To make sure that Apache is running, you can run "ApacheMonitor.exe" found in "Apache24/bin." After running that check the [notifications area](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/n/notiarea.htm) (that little menu on the right of the task bar that you open up with the tiny arrow) and there should be a small symbol that looks like the icon of the ApacheMonitor application. The symbol should have a green arrow in it if it's running. Otherwise, left-click it and select start.

Another option is to download a more pre-built windows binary of Apache from one of the links on the [Using Apache with Windows page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html). I recommend ApacheHaus. There is still set up required, but when I downloaded it and set it up on my windows 10 it seems to work fine.

I'm not a pro at server set up either, but I hope this helps.